# How do I create an edge on a non-standard shape?

Tags: modeling, edges, topology

I am trying to create a horizontal line around a corner but Blender won't allow me to do cuts with crtl+r.

My intent is to make 4 edges so that i can make it go inward (it's supposed to be the lid of a box)

[image]

Some extra info: I am unable to use the knife tool (K) because from the front and rear view the box is obstructed and I don't want to cut a line through the entire model.

If there is a way for me to add a Vert on an edge with it being able to slide, much like the crtl+r shortcut does for edges that would be a way.

Edit: This was marked as possible duplicate where the solution was using the knife tool but like I said above I'd like to avoid using this as I'll have to make it "cut-through" which will cut the entire length of a 6m long model with a bunch of details.

Comment: The solution will be the same, removing the Ngons (visible in the screenshot) and tris (if any) as they will prevent Loopcut from working. It isn't important whether you're dissolving or adding geometry when fixing, e.g. you can dissolve the edge in the top of the left cube so there aren't ngons on its sides. Knife tool won't cut through the model if you disable Cut-through

Comment: But the side which isn't allowing the loopcut is a plane with 4 corners, not an ngon, that's the reason I had to make a small triangle at the bottom. The thing with the knife is that I can't make the cut unless I allow it to cut-through because of where the side is hidden in the model.